# can't import tensoflow with GPU support correctly

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

my python version is 2.7.12

cuda version is 9.0

cudnn version is 7.0

and my OS is ubuntu 16.04

but when I import tensorflow , I have get the follow error message.

how I can solve it!

ImportError: libcusolver.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Comment: Please format your question to make it readable.

Comment: Solved! Just because the traditional installing method doesn't suit the cuda 9.0.

Comment: After I change CUDA9.0 with CUDA8.0, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had these issues in past. Please specify the tensorflow version you are trying to install. These are the possible solutions you can try:

Solution 1 -

1. Check if Cuda path is set in your ~/.bashrc file, It should be something like this `export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
           export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64\
                      ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}`
2. You should be able to run `nvcc -V`
3. If everything looks correct sometime you can solve the problem by just changing cuda-9.0 to just cuda in the path. Strange but that worked for me.

Solution 2-

1. Just create a symlink for files in your cuda/lib64 folder
2. Since you have cuda 9.0 installed your lib64 folder should have `libcusolver.so.9.0` check this.
3. If everything seems correct use `ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so.9.0 /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcusolver.so.8.0`
4. You will have to do this manually for 7-8 files.

Try it, or please report the error.

Cheers